# Custom ESLint plugin doesn't suggest auto-fix in editor

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

I created a custom eslinter plugin which warns the usage of a specific function.
It is working as expected, the only issue is that I want to suggest an autofix which will replace the function with another function. This is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    rules: {
        'no-registration-type-tealium': {
            create( context ) {
                return {
                    Identifier( node ) {
                        if ( 'CallExpression' === node.parent.type && 'registrationTypeTealium' === node.name ) {
                            context.report( {
                                node,
                                message: 'Do not use `registrationTypeTealium`, use `loadTealium` instead.',
                                suggest: [
                                    {
                                        desc: 'Replace with `loadTealium`',
                                        fix: ( fixer ) => {
                                            return fixer.replaceText( node, 'loadTealium' );
                                        },
                                    },
                                ],
                            } );
                        }
                    },
                };
            },
        },
    },
};
```

I use VSCode which has this suggestion bubble, I am trying to add the suggestion here but it isn't showing up, any ideas where I am going wrong?

[image]